# Pyspark, error:input doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema and extra trailing comma after columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, indexing, pyspark, hdfs

First I made two tables(RDD) to use following commands

```
rdd1=sc.textFile('checkouts').map(lambda line:line.split(',')).map(lambda fields:((fields[0],fields[3],fields[5]), 1) )
rdd2=sc.textFile('inventory2').map(lambda line:line.split(',')).map(lambda fields:((fields[0],fields[8],fields[10]), 1) )
```

The keys in first RDD are BibNum, ItemCollection and CheckoutDateTime. And when I checked the values for first RDD to use rdd1.take(2) it shows

```
[((u'BibNum', u'ItemCollection', u'CheckoutDateTime'), 1), ((u'1842225', u'namys', u'05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM'), 1)]
```

and similarly the keys in second RDD are BibNum, ItemCollection and Itemlocation. And the values are as following:

```
[((u'BibNum', u'ItemCollection', u'ItemLocation'), 1), ((u'3011076', u'ncrdr', u'qna'), 1)]
```

Once I created two RDDs, I tried to join those two to use `rdd3=rdd1.join(rdd2)`
After it, when I checked the value of rdd3 to use rdd3.take(2). Following error happened.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I do not know why it happend. Please enlighten me if you know the reason. If you have any doubts for my question or code, just let me know I will try to clarify it. Thanks

edit---
I put up my sample input data for each RDD

```
BibNum,ItemBarcode,ItemType,ItemCollection,CallNumber,CheckoutDateTime,,,,,,,
1842225,10035249209,acbk,namys,MYSTERY ELKINS1999,05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM,,,,,,,
1928264,10037335444,jcbk,ncpic,E TABACK,12/14/2005 05:56:00 PM,,,,,,,
1982511,10039952527,jcvhs,ncvidnf,VHS J796.2 KNOW_YO 2000,08/11/2005 01:52:00 PM,,,,,,,
2026467,10040985615,accd,nacd,CD 782.421642 Y71T,10/19/2005 07:47:00 PM,,,,,,,
2174698,10047696215,jcbk,ncpic,E KROSOCZ,12/29/2005 03:42:00 PM,,,,,,,
1602768,10028318730,jcbk,ncpic,E BLACK,10/08/2005 02:15:00 PM,,,,,,,
2285195,10053424767,accd,cacd,CD 782.42166 F19R,09/30/2005 10:16:00 AM,,,,Input,BinNumber,Date,BinNumber+Month
2245955,10048392665,jcbk,ncnf,J949.73 Or77S 2004,12/05/2005 05:03:00 PM,,,,,,,
770918,10044828100,jcbk,ncpic,E HILL,07/22/2005 03:17:00 PM,,,,,,,
```

.

```
BibNum,Title,Author,ISBN,PublicationYear,Publisher,Subjects,ItemType,ItemCollection,FloatingItem,ItemLocation,ReportDate,ItemCount,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3011076,A tale of two friends / adapted by Ellie O'Ryan ; illustrated by Tom Caulfield| Frederick Gardner| Megan Petasky| and Allen Tam.,O'Ryan| Ellie,1481425730| 1481425749| 9781481425735| 9781481425742,2014,Simon Spotlight|,Musicians Fiction| Bullfighters Fiction| Best friends Fiction| Friendship Fiction| Adventure and adventurers Fiction,jcbk,ncrdr,Floating,qna,09/01/2017,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2248846,Naruto. Vol. 1| Uzumaki Naruto / story and art by Masashi Kishimoto ; [English adaptation by Jo Duffy].,Kishimoto| Masashi| 1974-,1569319006,2003| c1999.,Viz|,Ninja Japan Comic books strips etc| Comic books strips etc Japan Translations into English| Graphic novels,acbk,nycomic,NA,lcy,09/01/2017,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3209270,Peace| love & Wi-Fi : a ZITS treasury / by Jerry Scott and Jim Borgman.,Scott| Jerry| 1955-,144945867X| 9781449458676,2014,Andrews McMeel Publishing|,Duncan Jeremy Fictitious character Comic books strips etc| Teenagers United States Comic books strips etc| Parent and teenager Comic books strips etc| Families Comic books strips etc| Comic books strips etc| Comics Graphic works| Humorous comics,acbk,nycomic,NA,bea,09/01/2017,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1907265,The Paris pilgrims : a novel / Clancy Carlile.,Carlile| Clancy| 1930-,786706155,c1999.,Carroll & Graf|,Hemingway Ernest 1899 1961 Fiction| Biographical fiction| Historical fiction,acbk,cafic,NA,cen,09/01/2017,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1644616,Erotic by nature : a celebration of life| of love| and of our wonderful bodies / edited by David Steinberg.,,094020813X,1991| c1988.,Red Alder Books/Down There Press|,Erotic literature American| American literature 20th century,acbk,canf,NA,cen,09/01/2017,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

edit----------------------------------------------
`date_count --> DataFrame[BibNum : string, ItemCollection : string, CheckoutDateTime : string, count : BigInt ]` .. shows likes this
but when I checked the value of it using date_count.take(2) , it shows error like this : Input doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 6 fields are required while 7 values are provided.

df_final schema looks like this: `DataFrame[BibNum:string, ItemType:string, ItemCollection:string, ItemBarcode:string, CallNumber:string, CheckoutDateTime:string, Title:string, Author:string, ISBN:string, PublicationYear:string, Publisher:string, Subjects:string, FloatingItem:string, ItemLocation:string, ReportDate:string, ItemLocation:string, : string , : string, : string .... : string , : string` ]

Comment: Please print out the data and show it to us.

Comment: You mean the input data?..

Comment: I put up my input data into the writings :)

Comment: @pissall I am not sure which data you meant, but if you meant the data for each RDD, I already put up in the writings such as [((u'BibNum', u'ItemCollection', u'CheckoutDateTime'), 1), ((u'1842225', u'namys', u'05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM'), 1)]

Comment: I got it. What I don't understand is why have you mapped it like that? I mean by using, map(lambda fields:((fields[0],fields[3],fields[5]), 1))

Comment: Can you tell me what you're trying to achieve here? I think I already know, but once you confirm maybe I can help you better.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried to use three keys.. and One for the value part would be changed. I got this code some example..

Comment: I want to join rdd1, rdd2 with BibNum and ItemCollection which are common in each rdd, so I want to extract specific value such as which ItemLocation is empty by counting the checkoutDate and ItemCollection.

Comment: In short, my problem definition is to find out which ItemLocation will be available to put some books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll try to answer your question. The solution might be syntactically haywire but I'll try to do my best (I don't have an environment to test right now). Let me know if this is what you are looking for otherwise I can help you with fine tuning the solution.

Here is the documentation for [Join in Pyspark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join)

So when you read the files :

```
rdd1=sc.textFile('checkouts').map(lambda line:line.split(','))
rdd2=sc.textFile('inventory2').map(lambda line:line.split(','))
# Define the headers for both the files
rdd1_header = rdd1.first()
rdd2_header = rdd2.first()

# Define the dataframe
rdd1_df = rdd1.filter(lambda line: line != rdd1_header).toDF(rdd1_header)
rdd2_df = rdd2.filter(lambda line: line != rdd2_header).toDF(rdd2_header)

common_cols = [x for x in rdd1_df.columns if x in rdd2_df.columns]

df_final = rdd1_df.join(rdd2_df, on=common_cols)
date_count = df_final.groupBy(["BibNum", "ItemCollection", "CheckoutDateTime"]).count()
```

EDITS :

1) Your error : "pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Reference 'ItemCollection' is ambiguous, could be ItemCollection#3, ItemCollection#21" is due to multiple columns being generated after the join. What you need to do is include all common columns in your join. I will mention it in the code.

2) Another issue : Some of weird parts are added into the last part of each RDD, such as -- [Row(BibNum=u'1842225', ItemBarcode=u'10035249209', ItemType=u'acbk', ItemCollection=u'namys', CallNumber=u'MYSTERY ELKINS1999', CheckoutDateTime=u'05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM', =u'', =u'', =u'', =u'', =u'', =u'', =u'')

For this, you had mentioned your CSV file as follows :

```
BibNum,ItemBarcode,ItemType,ItemCollection,CallNumber,CheckoutDateTime,,,,,,,
1842225,10035249209,acbk,namys,MYSTERY ELKINS1999,05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM,,,,,,,
1928264,10037335444,jcbk,ncpic,E TABACK,12/14/2005 05:56:00 PM,,,,,,,
```

Now if you can see there are a lot of trailing commas after the date column. i.e. ',,,,,,,', which is giving those extra empty columns (after the split on commas) which you can drop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer first, but you know what this error is ?-- join() got an unexpected keyword argument 'on'

Comment: Probably you're using some other join() method. I have added the documentation link. It mentions the use of 'on' and 'how' for you to mention how you want to perform the join. You can use other ways of joining by using (rdd1_df.BibNum == rdd2_df.BibNum) as the condition.

Comment: Sir, actually I used cloudera but it didn't work for 'on' command so I tried it on google cloud platform so it worked fine. But other problem happend as following: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Reference 'ItemCollection' is ambiguous, could be ItemCollection#3, ItemCollection#21.;"

Comment: Some of weird parts are added into the last part of each RDD, such as -- [Row(BibNum=u'1842225', ItemBarcode=u'10035249209', ItemType=u'acbk', ItemCollection=u'namys', CallNumber=u'MYSTERY ELKINS1999', CheckoutDateTime=u'05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM', =u'', =u'', =u'', =u'', =u'', =u'', =u''),

Comment: Include all common columns in the list that is passed to 'on' so that it doesn't make duplicate columns. It's making duplicate columns of item collection

Comment: If your requirement is sufficed, please close the question by selecting the answer.

Comment: Hi, Sir.. I tried edited one but actually when I see my csv file(input file), it does not show trailing commas but when I see values in vm, it shows trailing commas in the end of normal columns. I don't know why.. and I am getting this following error: Input doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 6 fields are required while 7 values are provided.

Comment: Sir I am not sure why it is not working about your logic, if it happens from trailing commas after normal columns, is there any way to drop the trailing comma? I looked into CSV in it but there is no trailing comma showing.

Comment: There is an extra empty column for sure. You are accounting for 6 columns whereas there are 7 columns. The number of values getting passed is 7 values. Can you edit your question showing more context of this? I will add to my answer how to solve it.

Comment: Sir, I changed my title but I am not sure if you would expect it, thanks

Comment: I tried quite lots of ways yesterday, but for some reasons any of I tried did not work..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169160/discussion-between-pissall-and-).