# cannot join two RDD in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have two data frame called df1, df2, but when I try to join it, it cannot be done. Let me put up my schema for each dataframe and sample output for each.

```
df1
Out[160]: DataFrame[BibNum: string, CallNumber: string, CheckoutDateTime: string, ItemBarcode: string, ItemCollection: string, ItemType: string]

Row(BibNum=u'BibNum', CallNumber=u'CallNumber', CheckoutDateTime=u'CheckoutDateTime', ItemBarcode=u'ItemBarcode', ItemCollection=u'ItemCollection', ItemType=u'ItemType'),
 Row(BibNum=u'1842225', CallNumber=u'MYSTERY ELKINS1999', CheckoutDateTime=u'05/23/2005 03:20:00 PM', ItemBarcode=u'10035249209', ItemCollection=u'namys', ItemType=u'acbk')]



df2    
DataFrame[Author: string, BibNum: string, FloatingItem: string, ISBN: string, ItemCollection: string, ItemCount: string, ItemLocation: string, ItemType: string, PublicationDate: string, Publisher: string, ReportDate: string, Subjects: string, Title: string]

[Row(Author=u'Author', BibNum=u'BibNum', FloatingItem=u'FloatingItem', ISBN=u'ISBN', ItemCollection=u'ItemCollection', ItemCount=u'ItemCount', ItemLocation=u'ItemLocation', ItemType=u'ItemType', PublicationDate=u'PublicationYear', Publisher=u'Publisher', ReportDate=u'ReportDate', Subjects=u'Subjects', Title=u'Title'),
 Row(Author=u"O'Ryan| Ellie", BibNum=u'3011076', FloatingItem=u'Floating', ISBN=u'1481425730| 1481425749| 9781481425735| 9781481425742', ItemCollection=u'ncrdr', ItemCount=u'1', ItemLocation=u'qna', ItemType=u'jcbk', PublicationDate=u'2014', Publisher=u'Simon Spotlight|', ReportDate=u'09/01/2017', Subjects=u'Musicians Fiction| Bullfighters Fiction| Best friends Fiction| Friendship Fiction| Adventure and adventurers Fiction', Title=u"A tale of two friends / adapted by Ellie O'Ryan ; illustrated by Tom Caulfield| Frederick Gardner| Megan Petasky| and Allen Tam.")]
```

When I tried to join two using this command:

```
df3=df1.join(df2, df1.BibNum==df2.BibNum)
```

, there was no error but the dataframe looked like this which are having overlapped columns:

```
DataFrame[BibNum: string, CallNumber: string, CheckoutDateTime: string, ItemBarcode: string, ItemCollection: string, ItemType: string, Author: string, BibNum: string, FloatingItem: string, ISBN: string, ItemCollection: string, ItemCount: string, ItemLocation: string, ItemType: string, PublicationDate: string, Publisher: string, ReportDate: string, Subjects: string, Title: string]
```

And lastly, after I got df3(joined dataframe), when I tried df3.take(2), The error: `list index out of range` happened. 
What I look for as a result is I want to find out which which ItemLocation will be available by counting the books which days(checkoutDateTime) are borrowed the most.

Comment: do you see output when you do df3.show()? Your code works for me so I don't think the error is in df3.take(2). It must be somewhere else

Comment: No I cannot see df3.show() as well with same index error, and weird thing is I can only see the dataframe which has overlapped columns of df1 and df2.

Comment: can you explain `I can only see the dataframe which has overlapped columns of df1 and df2` and update the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the dataframe on common columns otherwise it will generate 2 conflicting columns of the same name from 2 different dataframes.

```
common_cols = [x for x in df1.columns if x in df2.columns]
df3 = df1.join(df2, on=common_cols, how='outer')
```

You can use outer join or left join based on your requirement. And please do not ask multiple questions for the same issue. You are already getting active answers at : [when trying to join two tables, happening IndexError: list index out of range in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849494/when-trying-to-join-two-tables-happening-indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-in/49849827?noredirect=1#comment86744628_49849827)